# How to process large video in Matlab with for loop and without memory error

Tags: matlab, memory, video, for-loop, out-of-memory

I'm new to Matlab processing, and I would like to read and process a large video (more than 200k frames) inside a "for loop" (or without it). In particular, i would like to:

1. read the video with VideoReader,
2. subdivide the video into n-epoch of 1000 frames each ones,
3. process every epoch of 1000 frames, reading: the first frame of the epoch, skip two, read the frame, skip two, and so on (for example i=1:3:nFrames),
4. considering every epoch i need to convert every "RGB-frame" read into im2bw
5. after the conversion i need to make the "corr2" 2D cross-correlation considering the first video frame ("mov(1,1).cdata") and every frames read within the epoch,
6. store the result from "corr2" into a vector.

In summary, this is what i need to do. Thank You all

---

This is what I have so far, about "corr2":

```
for frame_ind = 1 : nFrames
  mov(frame_ind).cdata = im2bw(rgb2gray(read(xyloObj,frame_ind)),0.20);      
end

%% Corr2 to compare BW video frames
for frame_ind2 = 1:(frame_ind-1)
    R(frame_ind2)=corr2(mov(1,frame_ind2).cdata,mov(1,frame_ind2+1).cdata);
end

 TF= isnan(R); 
 g=sum(TF);
 f=(length(R)-g);


if (g~=(length(R))) 
  %%If Part has errors 
  disp('"Part_1" has video interferences/noise/problems, see "Testresult.txt" for more information.');
 else 
  %%If Part has not errors  
  displ=strcat('"Part_1" has not video interferences/noise/problems.');
 end
```

Comment: do you want to process three frames at a time, or do you want to take one frame, skip two, take the next, skip two, etc..? Also if you are running out of memory, don't store all frames read, simply read the frame, process it, read the next frame overwriting the previous value...

Comment: I would like to subdivide the whole video in n-epoch of 1000 frames, and each epoch should be processed "...  one frame, skip two, take the next, skip two, etc..".

Comment: @8bit_Biker so instead of going from frame `1, 4, 7, 10, ... end`, you want to go from `1:1000` in steps of three and then from `1001:2000` in steps of three. is that correct?

Comment: @8bit_Biker: also please describe what type of processing you intend to do the frames. For example if you need to do correlation on successive frames, obviously we'll have to store the last two one. As I explained, my code only store one frame at all times just to reduce memory used..

Comment: @Amro: I can make it with three for-loops: one for the first 1000 frames, one from 1001 to fix(nframes/1000), and the last from fix(nframes/1000) to nFrames... I think there is a better way to do it, but I can't set it properly.

Comment: @8bit_Biker: thank you. With the recent edit, it is much more clear now

Comment: @Amro the code provided by the OP is still pretty useless. At least the `corr2` and `im2bw` parts could be included.

Comment: @memyself: I just wanted to include what the OP already tried. Feel free to edit the question as you see fit (I think you can also suggest edits if you don't have the required rep)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version:

```
mov = VideoReader('movie.avi');
nFrames = mov.NumberOfFrames;

len = 1000;     %# epoch length
step = 3;       %# step size

%# indices of each epoch
indices = bsxfun(@plus, 1:step:len, (0:ceil(nFrames/len-1))'*len);   %#'
indices = num2cell(indices,2);
indices{end}(indices{end}>nFrames) = [];

%# loop over each epoch
corr_coef = cell(size(indices));
for e=1:numel(indices)
    %# read first image in epoch
    img1 = read(mov, indices{e}(1));
    img1 = rgb2gray(img1);            %# instead of im2bw(img1, graythresh(img1))

    %# read rest of images in epoch
    corr_coef{e} = zeros(1,numel(indices{e})-1);
    for f=2:numel(indices{e})
        img2 = read(mov, indices{e}(f));
        img2 = rgb2gray(img2);

        %# compute corr2 between the two images
        corr_coef{e}(f-1) = corr2(img1,img2);
    end
end
```

The cell array `corr_coef` contains the correlation coefficients in each epoch, where each cell contains a vector `corr_coef{e}(i)` of `corr2` between the first frame and the (i+1)-th frame.

Note that if one of the frames is constant (all black for example), the 2D correlation coefficient is simply NaN (zero divided by zero in the [formula‌](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/corr2.html#f1-227958)​)

Comment: Note that if one of the frames is constant (all black for example), the 2D correlation coefficient is simply NaN (zero divided by zero in the [formula](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/corr2.html#f1-227958))

Comment: Thank You.. I'll try to use it now! ;)

Comment: Same problem... As I wrote for the other answer.. It returns all-NaN-array... It's impossible... Probably there are some problem with the indexing of corr2 function... Anyway... THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR HELP!!!

Comment: again, we don't know your video file, so there's not much we can do. debug your code and look at the individual `corr2()` output.

Comment: ok this is what I've wrote in my code.. try to look at this..(read at the  top of the "Question")

Comment: Obviously, my code refers to a step-by-step video reading and processing

Comment: @8bit_Biker: did you see my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718704/how-to-process-large-video-in-matlab-with-for-loop-and-without-memory-error/11724159#comment15555705_11724159) about `corr2` with constant-value frames producing `NaN`? I also think you should be converting to grayscale images not binary images (RGB2GRAY instead of IM2BW).

Comment: @8bit_Biker: I just tested it on a random video I had. The correlation coefficients in the first epoch are all NaN. This was expected because the first frame in the video is all black... The following epochs were better (values between -1 and 1). My advice rethink your algorithm, do you really want to compare against all black video frames?

Comment: yes..In effect, I correct the code and now it works... I feel like an idiot!!! :( You are very kind and patient! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Amro:The goal of this program is to process large video (more than 2h) and investigate "frame-by-frame" if something has changed from the first frame. For example: if the first frame contains only a white "entity" (independently by form or other characteristics) surrounded by black backgrounds, I should investigate if this entity disappear or move during the movie. Or, another example, if the first frame is totally black (in effect it is impossible if you consider an RGB/greyscale element, because of intrinsic quantization noise), discover if a white entity appear.

Comment: I thought to consider only the white/black dualism (resulting from im2bw conversion) to have more simplicity... Any suggestion will be very well accepted.. Thank you all!

Comment: @8bit_Biker: Sounds to me like you are doing something similar to foreground/background segmentation/tracking in videos. There are [algorithms](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/vision/ref/vision.foregrounddetectorclass.html) designed for that

Comment: To avoid NaN, I've tried to make the corr2 function between the all frames (step by step) and a "all-white" frames (considered as the first video frame), got with imcomplement function. I always get NaN corr2 vector.. why?? Apply corr2 function to an all-white frame and a black frame with white element inside, should return "NaN" as a result???

Comment: If I try to use corr2 with two all-white frames, it returns to me "NaN"..why???I expect 1, because frame are equal.. Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: @8bit_Biker: if any of the images is all constant (whether its zero, one, or any other value), the correlation will be zero divided by zero, thus NaN. If you read the [equation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/corr2.html#f1-227958) used in `corr2`, you see that in each image and for each pixel, we subtract the mean value, then we do the sum of the products. If an image is all constant-value, then any pixel minus the mean is zero. Which is why we end up with zero divided by zero

Comment: Yes..I read it... I've decided to use another algorithm to solve the problem.. Anyway thank you all very much for your suggestions.. ;) I'm starting to love Matlab, for it's power and flexibility!

Answer (score 0):

```
% create video handle and get number of frames
vidObj = VideoReader(video_file);
nFrames = get(vidObj, 'NumberOfFrames');

blocksize = 1000;
BlocksIDs = 1:blocksize:nFrames;
nBlocks = numel(BlocksIDs);

frame_step = 3;

% cell array with all correlations values grouped by block
xcorrs_all_blocks = cell(1, nBlocks);

for j = 1 : nBlocks

    % if this is the last block, process until the last frame
    if j == nBlocks
        last_frame = nFrames;
    % otherwise, read until next block
    else
        last_frame = BlocksIDs(j + 1);
    end
    % compute the frame numbers that we want to look at
    frame_indices = BlocksIDs(j) : frame_step : last_frame;
    nFrames = numel(frame_indices);

    first_frame = [];
    % pre-allocate array holding the in-block corr2 values.
    xcorrs_this_block = nan(1, nFrames-1);

    for k = 1 : nFrames

        % read-in raw frame from video file.
        raw_frame = read(vidObj, frame_indices(k));            
        % determine level for bw conversion - this might help.
        level = graythresh(raw_frame);
        raw_frame = im2bw(raw_frame, level);

        if k == 1
            % save current frame as first frame for later corr2 processing
            first_frame = raw_frame;
        else
            % calc the correlation between the first frame in the block and each successive frame
            xcorrs_this_block(k-1) = corr2(first_frame, raw_frame);
        end


    end

    % save all xcorr values into global cell array.
    xcorrs_all_blocks{j} = xcorrs_this_block;

end
```

Comment: I'll hope this works... I'll try it now.. thank you very very much

Comment: @8bit_Biker I don't know what your video looks like. I also don't know whether `im2bw` is the right thing todo (since again, I don't know your video). try maybe to calculate the threshold with `level = graythresh(I);`. I've added the `graythresh` code to my answer. maybe it helps.

Comment: Maybe it should have some errors with the corr2 function: i have a video with some frames black and some white, but corr2 consider all equal...In fact the "xcorrs_all_blocks" it is full of "NaN". Instead I expect some coefficient (ranging from 0 to 1) depending on whether  frames are less or more similar to the first video frame. Why??

Comment: @8bit_Biker again, I don't know anything about your video, but it seems like something goes wrong calculating the `corr2`. set a breakpoint there and see what the output is. are you sure that ALL values of `xcorrs_all_blocks` are NaN? what about `xcorrs_all_blocks{1}(1)`?

Comment: My video is a sequence of black frames. Sometimes some frames with black background and white string (a sort of video interference/noise) will appear. The goal is to determine if the video has this "special frames" within or not. I thought to use corr2 function to process the frames. The video is 25fps, and to get speed in processing, i would like to consider one frames of three

Comment: :T his new version you've wrote causes this error:
"Cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object.

Error in provaNewcode (line 97)
            xcorrs_this_block{k-1} = corr2(first_frame,
            raw_frame);"

Comment: no, the code you are using is not the same as my answer. the line in question reads: `xcorrs_this_block(k-1) = corr2(first_frame, raw_frame);`

Comment: ehm... don't consider (line 97) because I've added some codeline to get the video via browser...

Comment: what I'm saying is don't use `{}` but `()`, so that you have `xcorrs_this_block(k-1)`

Comment: Ok.. Now works..sorry for my mistake... but it returns to me a all-NaN-vector...It is wrong, because it should return to me 6/7 corr-coef at least.. :(

Comment: again, we don't know your video file, so there's not much we can do. debug your code and look at the individual `corr2()` output.