# What's the most memory-efficient way of processing a video on MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, video, video-processing

This is the help tutorial for reading a video:

```
    xyloObj = VideoReader('xylophone.mpg');

    nFrames = xyloObj.NumberOfFrames;
    vidHeight = xyloObj.Height;
    vidWidth = xyloObj.Width;

    % Preallocate movie structure.
    mov(1:nFrames) = ...
        struct('cdata', zeros(vidHeight, vidWidth, 3, 'uint8'),...
               'colormap', []);

    % Read one frame at a time.
    for k = 1 : nFrames
        mov(k).cdata = read(xyloObj, k);
    end

    % Play back the movie once at the video's frame rate.
    movie(mov, 1, xyloObj.FrameRate);
```

But I'm trying to process a huge video, and if I try the above code my computer runs out of memory. I've thought about reading some frames, processing them, reading some more, processing, until all the frames have been processed (of course, deleting the old frames as the code goes, to mantain a low-level memory comsumption), but I'm not sure this is the best way, since I've never processed video with MATLAB.

Is there a best-practice for this kind of situation? Did I miss something?

Thanks!

Comment: similar question: [How to process large video in Matlab with for loop and without memory error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11718704/97160)

Answer (score 2):

The most memory efficient way to process video is to load, process, and write a single frame at a time. Then you only ever have one frame in memory.

That's probably quite inefficient in terms of disk IO, however. A good technique for any type of large file is to process in chunks. In this case you would read, process, and write N frames at a time. You need to choose N to use an appropriate amount of memory on your system. Generally speaking, a larger N will be faster right up until you hit the memory limit.