# Processing very huge video files in Matlab

Tags: matlab, video-processing

I am new to MATLAB, I have few videos of ~100GB each (10hrs duration). I want to calculate some features on every nth frame of the video. I have followed [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11723045/5530736) But my computer sleeps for just finding number of frames in one video. i.e.

```
nFrames = get(vidObj, 'NumberOfFrames');
```

Is there any faster way to process huge videos like I have as this seems to be very slow. Also I have tried looking in internet but didnt find any reasonable solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 100GB, are you processing uncompressed videos? My first attempt would be to create manageable pieces, split your video in easy-to manage segments (maybe 1h). Using direct stream copy it should not take much longer than copying a file of that size.

Comment: The code uses an old syntax, `vidObj.NumberOfFrames` is the new, but I don't think this will make any difference. Just be aware that there might be further issues with that code which are not fully compatible to recent MATLAB versions.

Comment: I tried `vidObj.NumberOfFrames` as well but that didnt make any difference. And I dont think splitting video in to pieces would be good for me in sense of application.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab is dogslow,so you can use ffmpeg instead. Your specific functionality being kept aside, you can extract individual images from a video using below command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf fps=60 out%d.png
```

Ffmpeg video processing is way faster compared to Matlab video processing.